# Putting element next to a centered element on a line containing a floated element

Tags: html, css, css-float

How do I put the `smiley`(yellow background) immediately after the centered word `Peter`(red background) in [this](http://jsbin.com/urodit/14/edit) example?

Answer (score 1):

If you give `.name` the `position: relative` property, you can declare a pseudo-element for it, which is absolutely positioned.

```
.name:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  content: ': )'; /* the space is non-braking */
}
```

http://jsbin.com/urodit/20/edit

Comment: I won't be able to use this because for the real case I am using an image instead of `: )` so I won't be able to place this in content(my fault for underspecifying the problem). However, I wouldn't be very fond of this because content is better kept in the html and it doesn't allow you to place more then one element to the right of it.

Comment: You could display the image as a background-image. But you're right: HTML is the better choice for content. However, if you wanna share some more informations about your project (fixed or variable width of images and so on), maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with floats like this: http://jsbin.com/urodit/26/

Some googling of 3 column layouts may help you find ideas if this isn't exactly what you want too.

```
.toggle-me {
background-color: green;
float:left;
} 

.name {
background-color: red;
float:left; 
width:40px;
margin:auto;
}

.description {
background-color: yellow;
width: 20px;
float:left;
}

.container-one{
 float:right;
 width:100%;

}

.favourite-food {
background-color: orange;
float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://jsbin.com/urodit/30/edit
Added `.container-one { text-align: center; }` and `.name { display: inline-block; }` to center the name. Then `.description { display: inline-block; }` to make it go after the name. Also removed `.name { margin: auto; }` because it's no longer necessary. And added `.name { text-align: left; }`.
Note the HTML comment after `.name` and before `.description`:

```
<div class="container-one">
    <div class="toggle-me">|Toggle|</div>
    <div class="name">Peter</div><!--
 --><div class="description">: )</div>
</div>
```

This is to remove the white space between inline-block elements, caused by the line-breaks and indentation of the code itself. If you don't want to remove the white space just remove the HTML comment.

Comment: `Peter` is not centered here though, compare with the original.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsbin.com/urodit/57/edit) is an ugly solution. It is not a nice solution since you need to fiddle with the `width` of the element that is floated on the right. You also need to put the element that will be on the right of your centered element *before* the centered element in your html.

**If anyone is able to post a cleaner solution I will accept that answer instead of this one.**